# React Native IOS Build getting Rejected by App store

Tags: react-native, axios, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

I am using Axios for Api Calls.The App works Fine in Real Devices and Simulator but App store is Rejecting it as some Post API's are not working at there end.
Did anyone Faced similar issues?

Comment: did you check the following Application Transport Security to allow http in info.plist

Comment: yeah @Abd i have already done that